# Программа не видит файл по относительному пути, но видит по абсолютному

Tags: c#, core

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
{
  "Config": {
    "FileName": "Certificates\\certif.pr.p12"
  }
}
```

А если пишу полный путь то находит.
Как сделать так чтобы программа видела файл по относительному путю?

Comment: Если файл лежит в проекте - поставьте у него свойство copy to output folder

Answer (score 1):

*"по относительному путю" - относительно чего?*

Устанавливать текущий директорий.

Comment: И я шепчу дрожащие губами: "Велик могучим русский языка!" (Плюс не мой, имху - до ответа не дотягивает)

Comment: @AK Не знал, что по последним инструкциям ВЦСПС слово "директория" приказано считать женского рода.

Comment: Ну, если вы настаиваете на данном варианте, то пожалуй откачу - всё-таки авторский вариант. Но да, для меня правильный вариант - "директория".

Comment: Каталог! И вопрос решен))) интересно, а папка какого рода :) мой папка вроде мужского.

Answer (score 1):

Это конфигурационный файл json? Есть рабочая директория, есть папка где находится файл. Как в командной строке. В строке указана текущая директория. Если мы находимся в папке

> С:\Users\Username> C:\Progs\myprog.exe

В таком случае папка **Certificates** с содержимым должна находиться в **С:\Users\Username\**, а не в **C:\Progs\**

Откройте любой ярлык: там есть **путь до объекта** и **Рабочая папка**, как правило они совпадают.
Как раз *Путь до объекта - C:\Progs\myprog.exe*, а *рабочая папка - С:\Users\Username\*.

В моем примере в профиле каждого пользователя должна быть папка **Certificates** со своими сертификатами - **С:\Users\Username\Certificates\**.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы С:\Users\Username\ - заполнялось само